# How to solve java.io.InvalidClassException: org.apache.solr.client.solrj.SolrQuery

Tags: java, apache-spark, solr, solrj

I have written the following code to query solr and do some operations on the document set using Spark and solrj:

```
SolrQuery sq = new SolrQuery();
sq.set(key, JobUtils.removeFrontEndQuotesWithBackSlash(queryParams.get(key).render()));
JavaRDD<SolrDocument> tempRDD = solrRDD.queryShardsBIL(sq,
                        paramsObj.get("splitField").render().replaceAll("\"", ""),
                        Integer.parseInt(paramsObj.get("splitsPerShard").render().replaceAll("\"", "")),
                        paramsObj.get("exportHandler").render().replaceAll("\"", ""));

combinedRDD = combinedRDD.union(tempRDD);
combinedRDD.mapToPair(new SolrJobMapper1(jobConfig))
                    .reduceByKey(new SolrJobReducer1(jobConfig))
                    .foreachPartition(new SolrJobPartitionIndexer1(JobUtils.removeFrontEndQuotes(paramsObj.get("zkHost").render()),
                    JobUtils.removeFrontEndQuotes(paramsObj.get("solrCollection").render()),
                    Boolean.parseBoolean(JobUtils.removeFrontEndQuotes(paramsObj.get("doCommit").render())),accum,JobUtils.removeFrontEndQuotes(paramsObj.get("uniqueIdField").render())));
```

When I run the job on spark server I get following error:

```
java.io.InvalidClassException: org.apache.solr.client.solrj.SolrQuery; local class incompatible: stream classdesc serialVersionUID = -323500251212286545, local class serialVersionUID = -7606622609766730986
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.initNonProxy(ObjectStreamClass.java:616)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNonProxyDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1623)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readClassDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1518)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1774)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1351)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2000)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1924)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1801)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1351)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2000)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1924)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1801)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1351)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2000)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1924)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1801)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1351)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:371)
    at org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaDeserializationStream.readObject(JavaSerializer.scala:76)
    at org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaSerializerInstance.deserialize(JavaSerializer.scala:115)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:194)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Whereas it works fine if I run it locally from main method. I am using the same solrj-6.1.0 in both environment. What am I missing here ?

Comment: Have you checked for the points mentioned here: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/InvalidClassException.html

Comment: Please post the source of `SolrJobMapper1` class and `SolrJobPartitionIndexer1`.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose `SolrQuery` is not serializable from Spark.

Not sure how you have implemented Solr queries, would be interesting if you post the source of `SolrJobMapper1` class and `SolrJobPartitionIndexer1`, but for this kind of works I use and strongly suggest [Lucidworks Spark/Solr Integration](https://github.com/lucidworks/spark-solr).